# how to read large csv or json file using nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js

any one can suggest me to read huge .csv or .json file using nodejs.

**i have a 30GB .CSV file, and 26GB json file**

i need to read file data and save it into database in **json format**

please help me to find the solution.

Comment: Dear abhimaniu, you need to review your system architecture and forget saving such large amount of data in json format.

Comment: Probably you'd want to open the file as a stream, and then maybe use some sort of streaming parser. e.g. [JSONStream](https://www.npmjs.com/package/JSONStream) and [csv-parser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/csv-parser). Those are just two I saw when searching npmjs.com...I'm sure there are others.